# How to add dot to regex

Tags: regex, validation, spring-annotations

```
@Pattern(regexp="^\\w{8,}")
private String username;
```

This pattern can only consist of numbers, letters and the underscore character.

How can I add the dot (.) to the pattern

Thanks

Comment: simple `@Pattern(regexp="^[.\\w]{8,}")` i think you must need to add end of the line anchor also like `@Pattern(regexp="^[.\\w]{8,}$")`

Comment: it works in both cases

Comment: no,  first one finds a match in `foo.bar.buz][p]\p` but the second  won't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, it might be easier to understand if you explicitly define all valid characters:

```
@Pattern(regexp="^[A-Za-z0-9_.]{8,}")
private String username;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add end of the line anchor also.

```
@Pattern(regexp="^[.\\w]{8,}$")
```